# DB Error: no such field afer civicrm_domain truncate

Tags: drupal

In an attempt to solve an issue of

> 'Please make sure the folder is writable' in
>   .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/IDS/Monitor.php

I started looking for solutions in the forums. I followed an advise which became fatal for me. The advise can be read here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=5390.msg41785#msg41785 , namely to truncate civicrm_domain, which someone confirmed to be effective. It was effective for me in that it broke civi completely. Now after log-in I get everywhere the error:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: no
>   such field

How to repair civicrm_domain?

Answer (score 2):

Try restore that one table from a mysql backup.

If you don't have a backup - then try populate the id, name, description, version, contact_id. Set config_backend, locales and locale_custom_strings to NULL (i.e. their default) - these will be regenerated - as you reconfigure your CiviCRM (settings, components, countries, currencies, etc). This is for a 4.6.x site

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would if weren't that stupid to have no backup available. I tried using a back-up of another (single language) instance of CiviCRM, but that did not help. If someone could explain what are the different column values, may be I could recreate it myself. But may be it is just faster to reinstall from scratch.

Comment: I've updated my answer above. Give that a try.

Comment: Sorry KarinG, had no time to loose, ended up reinstalling and reconfiguring. Now working on a install module that will do all the reconfiguring for me. This will allow me to start from scratch at any time and include it in GIT versioning.  I hope your answer is useful for others or for me in the future.